# variance for $2$ head appear in a row when we tosses coin $10$ times

Tags: probability

> A coin is tossed $10$ times. Let $X$ be the number of times $2$ heads appear in a row. What is ${\rm Var}(X)$?

What I tried:  Total number of ways $2^{10}$

Now if $2$ head appear in a row  exactly $1$ time:

$\text{HHTTTTTTTT}$ which can be done by $\displaystyle\frac{9!}{1!\cdot 8!}=9.$

If $2$ head appear exactly $2$ times. Then $\text{HHHTTTTTTT}$ which can be done by$\displaystyle\frac{8!}{1!\cdot 7!}=8.$

Similarly $2$ head appear exactly $3$ times is $7$ ways.

So mean $$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{2^{10}}\sum^{9}_{k=1}k=\frac{45}{2^{10}}$$

And $$var{X}=\sum p_{i}X_{i}-\bigg(\bar{X}\bigg)^2$$

Is my process is right?  If not then how do I solve it?

Comment: I think there are many, many more ways for two heads to appear in a row. For example, HHTTTHTHTH.

Comment: You could use an indicator function, first compute $E[X]$, then $E[X^2]$.